# How to get the difference in time using javascript?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

im trying to get the current time `timeNow` in javascript and at the end of the script get 
`timeEnd` which is when the script finished executing for example:

```
newDate = new Date();
timeNow = newDate.getTime();

for(i=0; i < 5; i ++){

    console.log("printing" + i);
}

timeEnd = timeNow - newDate.getTime();

console.log(timeEnd);
```

i want to get the time it took to excute this script in seconds or milliseconds, but the result is 0. i don't see why, can you help me thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Date` object does not keep ticking once it's constructed, it only represents a single instant in time.

You need to re-evaluate the time at the end of the script and then compare that value with the first one.

Note that on modern ES5 browsers you can use the "static" [`Date.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) function to get the current time.  This is less expensive that constructing a whole new `Date` object.  On older browsers you can emulate this function with this shim:

```
Date.now = Date.now || function() {
    return +(new Date);
};
```

At which point the required code becomes:

```
var start = Date.now();

// do your stuff here
...

var end = Date.now();

var elapsed = end - start;
```

FWIW, your simple loop reports 2ms when run on the Chrome console on my laptop.

Comment: it still gives me zero, by the way im not trying to measure this simple loop, i was just giving an example.

Comment: @user1551482 I can assure you this (and the previous version) are correct.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you create only a single `Date` object. These don't change; you will have to do:

```
timeEnd = timeNow - new Date().getTime();
```

(note the blank between `new` and `Date`)

Comment: that's actually not legal syntax for `new Date`

Comment: ah, actually `new Date` is legal (I thought the empty constructor params were required) but the alternative would have to been to write `(new Date).getTime()`.  I was the addition of `.getTime()` that broke your original answer because that `.` binds more tightly than `new`.

Answer (score 1):

```
var t = new Date().getTime();
// code
console.log(new Date().getTime() - t);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it takes less than a millisecond to perform 5 iterations I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use

starttime = Number(new Date());

endtime = Number(new Date());

Answer (score 0):

I actually don't think it is iterating in less than an millisecond.  It think the problem is that when you call `newDate.getTime()` repeatedly it returns the same value each time.  The object, once you create it, is set at the time it was created.  You'll need to create a new `Date()` object to compare the original against.

From my Firebug Console:

```
>>> d = new Date()
Date {Thu Aug 23 2012 10:45:52 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)}
>>> d.getTime()
1345740352582
>>> d.getTime()
1345740352582
>>> d.getTime()
1345740352582
>>> d.getTime()
1345740352582
```

I can assure you that I didn't manually make the calls to `d.getTime()` in less than a millisecond.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Do this

```
newDate = new Date();
timeNow = newDate.getTime();

for(i=0; i < 50; i++){
    console.log("printing" + i);
}

futureDate = new Date()
timeEnd =  futureDate.getTime();
timeLength = timeEnd - timeNow;


console.log(timeLength);
```